# How to write xml into a CSV file in powershell 3?

Tags: xml, powershell, csv

I have the following XML code (cut down massively) that i need to write to a csv file in powershell 3. the powershell code at the bottom is how far I've gotten, it can write the whole XML document into the console but doesn't write the xml into the csv.

The xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataReport>
    <ApiKeyId>1521</ApiKeyId>
    <Timestamp>2014-05-01 11-06-42</Timestamp>
<DataReportContent>
<Row><RowTypeCode RowTypeId="3297" Label="The University of Edinburgh">10007790</RowTypeCode>
    <Year Id="10" Label="2009/10" />
    <Value ValueTypeId="3517-3508">9592</Value><FieldCode FieldId="4502" Label="Undergraduate">2</FieldCode>
    <FieldCode FieldId="6271" Label="Female">2</FieldCode>
</Row>
</DataReportContent>
</DataReport>
```

The powershell

```
[xml]$Xmlvar = Get-Content C:\Users\dantrobus\documents\csvfile.csv
$rows = $Xmlvar.DataReport.DataReportContent.row
foreach ($row in $rows)
{
     write-host $row.RowTypeCode,$row.year,$row.FieldCode
     Export-Csv -path C:\Users\dantrobus\documents\csvfile.csv -InputObject $row.RowTypeCode,$row.year,$row.FieldCode -append
}
```

Comment: You should always provide a working sample. Xml file is incomplete, and you're missing a csv-sample to show us how the csv should look like, considering the elements you want to export to csv includes both a value and attributes.

Comment: sorry, i made a mistake on the formatting of the XML. fixed it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($row in $rows)
{
    # next line is for debug only, so you can see what's being processed
    # in the console window
    $row.RowTypeCode,$row.year,$row.FieldCode 

    # this line pipes the objects for processing
    $row.RowTypeCode,$row.year,$row.FieldCode |
    Export-Csv -path C:\Users\dantrobus\documents\csvfile.csv -append -NoTypeInformation
}
```